# How to join a String array to a int array and sort by number (higher to lower) in Android?

Tags: java, android, arrays, sorting

I have two arrays:

```
int[] sinais = new int[arraySinais.length];
String[] arraySSID = new String[] { };
```

And I joined them into one array:

```
String[] arrayScan = new String[arraySinais.length];
for (int i = 0; i < arraySSID.length; i++) {
    arrayScan[i] = arraySSID[i] + " " + sinais[i];
}
```

But now I need to sort this new array by numbers in a decreasing order and put an `Image` inside `ListView` depending the numbers, and I do not have any idea how to do this.

Comment: That is not possible. Create your own class with the needed datatypes and make a comparator that uses the int value for sorting.

Comment: Side note: Please use lowerCamelCase for variable names.

Comment: Thanks Murat K., I will!

Comment: @CarlosUghini This time, I did it for you, because I couldn't resist. But next time, please do what Murat K. suggested.

Comment: Pass your data to some Map/HashMap, then use Map<Key, Value> map = new TreeMap<Key, Value>(yourMap); This will sort your data by keys.

Comment: @MCEmperor thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can use create your own object which contains the int and the string and use arraylist to sort

Answer (score 0):

First create your own custom Element (`Object`) which mainly consist of an `int number` and a `String string`.

```
public class Element implements Comparable<Element>{
    private int number;
    private String string;
    public Element(String string, int number) {
        this.number =number;
        this.string = string;
    }
    //create custom constructors if its allowed to define an element without a number or string
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    public void setNumber(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }
    public String getString() {
        return string;
    }
    public void setString(String string) {
        this.string = string;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Element e) {

        return number - e.number;
    }

}
```

Implement `comparable` as above to sort depending on the number value, but keep in my mind that your element won't sort stand alone `strings`.

If you want to sort your list depending on strings if a number doesn't exist use this implementation of `comparTo()` method:

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Element e) {
        if(e.number != 0) return number - e.number;
        return string.compareTo(e.string);
    }
```

While using implement a `List` of elements and use Collections `sort`() method and you are good to go:

```
List<Element> list = new ArrayList<>();
//add Elements
Collections.sort(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the method below, by `Bubble Sort`, and solve my problem:

```
>     for (int i = Sinais.length; i >= 1; i--){
>                         for (int j = 1; j < i; j++){
>                             if (Sinais[j-1]<Sinais[j]){
>                                 int aux = Sinais[j];
>                                 String aux2 = ArraySSID[j];
>                                 Sinais[j] = Sinais[j-1];
>                                 ArraySSID[j] = ArraySSID[j-1];
>                                 Sinais[j-1] = aux;
>                                 ArraySSID[j-1] = aux2;
>                             }
>                         }
>                     }
```